# Cron tab not working in custom module

Tags: php, magento, cron

I have created custom module.In which i created a cron tab config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Test_Cron>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Test_Cron>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <testcron>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Test_Cron</module>
                    <frontName>testcron</frontName>
                </args>
            </testcron>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <testcron>
                <class>Test_Cron_Helper</class>
            </testcron>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <testcron>
                <class>Test_Cron_Model</class>
            </testcron>
        </models>
    </global>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <testingCron>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>*/5 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>testcron/observer::stockManager</model>
                </run>
            </testingCron>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

and this is my observer function.

```
<?php

 class Test_Cron_Model_Observer {

    public function stockManager(){
 Mage::log("Cron executed on ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),null,"yngCron.log");
}
}
?>
```

My magento system log are enabled.
when i manually call this method it works but it doesn't work by cron

```
Mage::getModel('testcron/observer')->stockManager();
```

Please help and let me know if i am missing something

Comment: have you checked your cron_schedule table??

Answer (score 1):

I have reviewd your given code this is correct. If your cron isn't being executed then you should execute the cron.sh script every 5 minutes.cron.sh file is exist at root folder and also check cron_schedule table in your magento database.In which you can check your cron scheduling.

For execute cron.sh script every 5 minutes see the command :- `*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.sh`

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Abhinav is correct if the cron.sh is not running on your server. However, if the cron is running it could be a couple other things. Make sure you flush/clear cache. Also, the system cron may not have enough permissions to create the log file. Check the cron_schedule database table to see if the job code is queued. You can queue the job manually by executing the cron.sh or cron.php. If the job doesn't queue after this, then it's most likely a cache or code issue.